# Using Spring Console Extension in WebLogic 10.3.4.0 with Spring 3.0.3

Tags: spring, weblogic

I've a Spring 3.0.3-based EAR+WAR which I'm deploying to WebLogic 10.3.4.0. I want to be able to see my the various framework Spring Beans at runtime via JMX and ideally in the WebLogic console.  (Note, these are NOT bean's we've written but the ones which come by default with Spring.)

Ideally we'd have been able to get it working with the WebLogic Spring Console Extension as described [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e14453/enable_console_ext.htm).  However after following all these steps (plus adding the weblogic-spring.jar to our WAR after we saw ClassNotFoundException errors in our WebLogic log when trying to navigate to the Spring tab in the WL Admin UI) we still see the following message in the WL console "This application does not use the Spring Framework or Spring MBean integration is not enabled." and no errors or messages in the log.

Does anyone know if it is possible to get Spring 3 apps working with the WebLogic 10.3.4.0 Spring Console Extension or should I try another route?

Answer (score 1):

Weblogic family 10.3.X supports only Spring Framework 2.5.X